# Firebase web client rewrites the error message returned by an https.onRequest function, how to prevent that?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I can not retrieve the message I send back from an "https.onRequest" function. The firebase client rewrites the message based on the error code and I can not recover the originally sent body or JSON.

**On Firebase Functions** :

```
exports.auth = functions.https.onRequest( (request, response) => {
    cors(request, response, async () => {
        try {
            return response.status(200).json({
                    data: "Hello"
                });

        } catch (error) {
            return response
                .status(403)
                .send('User not activated')
        }
    });
});
```

**All is ok if I analyze in the chrome development console the return of the request:**
Body (response.send) : "User not activated"

**But on the front side**

```
auth: function (email, password) {
    var register = firebaseFunctions.httpsCallable('auth');

    return register({
            email: email,
            password: password
        })
        .then(async (result) => {
            // ...
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            throw err
        });
}
```

**In my catch statement** :

```
err.message > permission-denied
err.details > undefined
err.code > 403
```

I do not know how to recover the message that I sent "User not activated" and that would allow me to process a 403 error code more accurately: the user can not connect because it is not activated.

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing up callable and regular HTTP type functions.  That's not going to work at all.

On your function side, you're declaring the function as a regular [HTTP type function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) using the onRequest callback.  This means you need to use an HTTP client library to access it.

On your client side, you're trying to invoke the function as a [callable type function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) using the Functions client SDK.  This requires that you declare your function using an onCall callback, not the onRequest callback that you're using now.  Callables have a [special protocol](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference) that's implemented by the client SDK.

The client and server have to match; right now they do not.  If you want to use a callable function, follow all the instructions in the linked documentation.  If you want a regular HTTP type function, you can't use Functions client SDK.  You have to use some other HTTP client library.