# Firebase iOS SDK calling cloud functions empty response

Tags: ios, node.js, swift, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I want to make a call to a Firebase cloud function to receive a json response and everything works as it should when calling the function from a browser.

However, when I make the same call from Firebase iOS SDK I receive another response. The properties are there but the values are empty.

Firebase function code in node:

```
const MyModel = require('./models/myModel');

exports.getCompanyContacts = functions.https.onRequest((request,response) => {
  //Doing irrelevant url modification
  axios.get(url)
    .then(res => {
      return response.status(200).send({data:new MyModel(res.data.data)})
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
      return response.send(500);
    });
});
```

MyModel class:

```
class MyModel {

   constructor(data) {
      console.log('domain: '+data.domain);
      this.domain = data.domain;
      this.organization = data.organization;
      this.emails = [];

      for(var i = 0; i < data.emails.length; i++){
        this.emails.push({email: data.emails[i].value, confidence: 
      data.emails[i].confidence})
      }
   }
}
```

iOS:

```
var functions = Functions.functions()
functions.httpsCallable("getCompanyContacts").call(["domain": domain]) { (result, error) in
        }
        if let contacts = result?.data as? [String: Any] {
            print(contacts)
        }
    }
```

Browser output (correct):

```
{"data":{"domain":"x.com","organization":"X","emails": 
[{"email":"contact.de@x.com","confidence":99}]}}
```

iOS app output (incorrect):

```
{domain = undefined;
emails = ();
organization = "<null>";}
```

Why isn't the iOS app receiving the same response as the browser? The funny thing is that when I tried to return a hardcoded js object like {test:'testing'} instead of MyModel everything worked fine even in the iOS app.

Comment: You're making the exact same mistake as the person in this other question, except you're doing it on iOS and not web.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/57452946/807126

Comment: Thank you Doug, that was the reason it didn't work yes!